# Show that $Y \cup Y'$ is well-ordered if and only if it is totally ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a partially ordered set, and let $Y$ and $Y'$ be well-ordered subsets of $X$. Show that $Y \cup Y'$ is well-ordered if and only if it is totally ordered.

Suppose $Y \cup Y'$ is totally ordered, and consider $A \subset Y \cup Y'$. $A$ is either a subset of $Y$ or $Y'$ or the union of both. In the first two cases, we can easily see that it has a minimal point. In the last case, we have that $A = T \cup T'$ for $T\subset Y$ and $T' \subset Y'$. $T \cup T' = T \cup (T'\setminus T)$. We know that $T$ and $(T'\setminus T)$ both have a minimal point, and let us call each one $t$ and $t'$, respectively. Then, the minimal point of $A$ exists and it must be either $t$ or $t'$. Since $Y \cup Y'$ is totally ordered, $t \le t'$ or $t' \le t$, so we can pick one.

I am struggling with the other direction, and I am not so sure why $Y \cup Y'$ cannot be partially ordered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $Y \cup Y'$ is well-ordered it is linearly ordered a fortiori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed here is that any well-ordered subset $T$ is automatically totally ordered : indeed, for two elements $t,t'$ in $T$ consider the subset $\lbrace t,t' \rbrace$ of $T$ : it has a minimum element by the well-ordering property.